# CosmosDB: Linq vs SqlQuerySpec Performance when querying CosmosDB

Tags: c#, linq, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have regularly performed LINQ predicates when querying CosmosDB specific documents. However, today I filled up my CosmosDB with 100 k+ documents. The performance was very slow. As the SQL Query in the Azure Portal was noticeably faster, I tried using SqlQuerySpec. Voilá! It worked so much faster.

Can anyone tell me the what is happening under the hood, when using Linq predicates with CosmosDB and why it slows my queries down?

The below code is used in my method for getting the document.
NB: The id is the partition key in this case.

```
        var collectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(CDBdatabase, CDBcollection);

        var sqlStatement = new SqlQuerySpec
        {
            QueryText = "SELECT * FROM c where c.id = @id",
            Parameters = new SqlParameterCollection()
                {
                          new SqlParameter("@id", consumerId),
                },
        };

        IDocumentQuery<T> query = documentClient.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(
            collectionUri,
            sqlStatement,
            .AsDocumentQuery();

        List<ConsumerDetails> results = new List<ConsumerDetails>();
        while (query.HasMoreResults)
        {
            results.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<ConsumerDetails>());
        }

        return results.FirstOrDefault();
```

Versus, the slower code:

```
        return documentClient.CreateDocumentQuery<ConsumerDetails>(
            collectionUri,
            .Where(f => f.Id == consumerId).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Slightly unrelated to your question but, if you are truly querying by a document's id, then `ReadDocument()` will be faster than a query, always (1 RU for 1KB doc, for example), as it doesn't need to go through the query engine.

Comment: You could call ToString() on IQueryable  obtained from LINQ chain and inspect the difference between manually built query with those one from CosomsDB linq provider.

Comment: Ok there are several things missing to give a good answer. Can you please post how your `ConsumerDetails` DTO looks like? Did you try providing the partition key value as part of the `FeedOptions` object on the LINQ approach? Did you try doing `.AsDocumentQuery` and `ExecuteNextAsync` on the linq query?

Answer (score 2):

The answer lies on the way you query.

The two code piece that you posted, are not the same.

For them to be the same the second one would have to look like this:

```
var collectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(CDBdatabase, CDBcollection);

var query = documentClient.CreateDocumentQuery<ConsumerDetails>(
    collectionUri)
    .Where(f => f.Id == consumerId)
    .AsDocumentQuery();

List<ConsumerDetails> results = new List<ConsumerDetails>();
while (query.HasMoreResults)
{
    results.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<ConsumerDetails>());
}

return results.FirstOrDefault();
```

In both cases it is SQL that you will execute against CosmosDB.
However in the LINQ case, a LINQ translator will kick in to convert your expression to a SQL query.

Also in the SQL example, because you are pointing directly to the lowercase `id` (which is the CosmosDB `id`) which is also the partition key, CosmosDB will recognise that and limit the query from a cross partition one to a partition specific one, making it faster and cheaper. The `.Where(f => f.Id == consumerId)` (with uppercase `Id`), once it goes through the LINQ provider, will be translated to `SELECT * FROM c where c.Id = consumerId` unless if there is a `JsonAttribute("id")` decorating the `Id` property. This means that you need to provide the `PartitionKey` value in the `FeedOptions` for the query.

Comment: Hi,

I have updated and compared my code with regards to your and @David Mokogon (in the comments above) feedback. I realize now that this is not entirely the same logic. Yes, I also forgot to mention that I am indeed using JsonAttributes for the ID.


However, this brings me to my following question:

Is there any performance issue by performing a LINQ query to AsEnumerable() vs performing a AsDocumentQuery + ExecuteNextAsync.

What happens under the hood on the AsEnumerable with regards to how / when I am firing requests to the CosmosDB?

Comment: Ofc there is. `AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();` will get all the documents matching the predicate synchronously first and then get the first or default value. `AsDocumentQuery + ExecuteNextAsync` will use the proper async pagination of CosmosDB so your application is not being locked.